# EF Core v5 - db connection login change causing issues with past migrations

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET Core 5 application that I have created. It is not ready to move to production. I was going to change the account used for the dbconnection so it has less permissions.

When I run and test with the other login, I get an error that migrations have not been applied and it wants me to apply all the past migrations.

Is there a way to get past this? The new account does not have permissions to apply migrations to the database.

What am I missing? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What permissions does the user have, especially on the migration history table?

Comment: I am such a dufus.  That was the only table I did not give this account permissions to.  That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Browne gave me the answer, I had forgot to give this account access to the Migrations table.  As soon as I did that, everything worked fine.